# .php files not being associated in VS Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

So I'm not sure what happened but within the last few weeks any '.php' file in my workspaces are being associated with "Plain Text", and if you click the lower right-hand corner to pick a language identifier 'PHP' is not listed anywhere.

I swear I used to have proper associations and my PHP syntax was getting highlighted. Has anyone else experienced this? Thus far my Google-fu has come up empty-handed.

version 1.21.1

-- UPDATE 
Notice that the file association in the lower right-hand corner is "plain text" and if you look at the language list (top center) PHP isn't even listed.

[image]

Comment: By chance did your file.associations setting get screwed up?

Comment: It appears to be empty ```"files.associations": {},```, I've uninstalled and reinstalled VSCode earlier today to try to fix the issue to no avail.

Comment: `files.associations` is empty for me but have no issues with `php` files not being recognized.

Comment: There is a built-in PHP extension in VS Code, so you could check it's state (installed, enabled). Maybe it's disabled (somehow)

Comment: @alefragnani do you know the steps to do so?

Comment: @alefragnani I found it, that was the issue, can you reply as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @john.weland that's great! Sure, I will reply..

Comment: @john.weland, please specify the extension name to enable to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built-in PHP extension in VS Code.

It must be *disabled/uninstalled* somehow, and that's why you don't see it available to select.

Comment: Thanks a ton, this fixed it. I checked extensions before but apparently builtin extensions are listed separately.

Comment: Hi, may I know the name of the this built-in extension? I got the same problem.

Comment: I did even uninstall and reinstall VS code which I believe should have brought back all the built-in extensions. But it didn't help.

Comment: Today, there are two, PHP Language Basics and PHP Language Features. Just search for "@builtin php" and you will see it.